# What was the first known organism to exhibit muscle growth based on activity?

Tags: evolution, muscles

Being able to grow bigger muscles to match an organism's personal habits seems like a pretty nifty feature since most organs grow to one specific size, aside from some stretching.

Was this a feature as long as muscle tissue has been around? If not which species had the ability first?

Comment: It would depend how you define a muscle no? This article has an informative take on the evolution of muscles. http://www.en.uni-muenchen.de/news/newsarchiv/2012/2012_woerheide.html